pgfplot: graph missing close to the endpoints of the domain
I would like to draw the binary entropy function.
I compile the following with lualatex (LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        /pgf/declare function={
                Hbinary(\x) = (and(\x > 0, \x < 1)) * (-\x * ln(\x) - (1-\x) * ln(1-\x)) / ln(2);
        },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=middle,
    x = 5.4cm,
    y = 5.4cm,
    xlabel=$p$,
    domain=0:1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1.05,
    xtick={1/2, 1},
    xticklabels={$\frac{1}{2}$, $1$},
    ytick={1},
    font=\footnotesize,
 ]
\addplot [domain = 0:1, smooth, thick, samples=150] {1 - Hbinary(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The problem is that the graph is not drawn close to the borders x=0 and x=1 of the domain. The domain of the drawn graph starts somewhere at 0.01 and ends at 0.99.
If I do a
\addplot [domain = 0:1, smooth, thick, samples=150] {1 - 4*(x - 1/2)^2};

instead (the graph looks somewhat similar), the problem is not present.
Explanation on the binary entropy function: The main term of the function is not defined for x=0 or x=1 (would involve a ln(0)). For that reason, I added the (and(\x > 0, \x < 1)) factor, which i hope should result in the value 0 for x=0 and x=1.
EDIT I have a suspicion now: When evaluating at x=0 (similarly at x=1), pgfplot is not clever enough to stop the evaluation after the zero factor (and(\x > 0, \x < 1)). Hence it still runs into an evaluation of ln(0), which probably gives kind of an invalid evaluation, resulting that the graph is not drawn for x=0 and x=1.
So I guess the question is: How can I rewrite the definition of my function such that Hbinary(0) and Hbinary(1) actually evaluate correctly to 0?

It works for me on texlive.net.

@azimut, please add the necessary boilerplate to make your code compilable. Which documentclass are you using? Do you load other packages? Which engine is used to compile?  Also for me it works ok...

I can't replicate the problem even with older TeX distributions. Please double-check that the code you post here results in the output you describe. Maybe an option from another plot interferes in your document. Make sure that you only set those options globally that you want to use globally. Otherwise set the options locally for each plot.

@Rmano: ok, done.

@JasperHabicht Thanks, I've added the exact code I compile.

The end points are missing because your function diverge, as shown in the log:
NOTE: coordinate (--,--,--) [--](was (0.0,-nan,--) [--]) has been dropped because it is unbounding (in 2).
NOTE: coordinate (--,--,--) [--](was (1.0,-nan,--) [--]) has been dropped because it is unbounding (in 2).

You should use
restrict y to domain=0:1

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.16,
  /pgf/declare function={
    Hbinary(\x) = (and(\x > 0, \x < 1)) * (-\x * ln(\x) - (1-\x) * ln(1-\x)) / ln(2);
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      axis lines=middle,
      x = 5.4cm,
      y = 5.4cm,
      xlabel=$p$,
      domain=0:1,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=1.1,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1.05,
      xtick={1/2, 1},
      xticklabels={$\frac{1}{2}$, $1$},
      ytick={1},
      font=\footnotesize,
      restrict y to domain=0:1,
    ]
    \addplot [domain = 0:1, smooth, thick, samples=150] {1 - Hbinary(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Many thanks for your analysis!

I found a solution: Removing the line compat=1.16 from pgfplotsset, the graph gets drawn on the full domain including 0 and 1.
The strange thing is that according to the logfile, I guess compat=1.18 should be the newest version (at least for the installed texlive package). However, the problem also occurs with compat=1.18. The only way I found to settle the problem is to completely remove the compat=... line.
